# SQL Error: 900 when running update query with multiple fields

Tags: oracle, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Running JPA `native` query with multiple fields from SQL developer console works, but the same query results in SQL Error: 900, SQLState: 42000 from JPA repository.

Query in JPA -

```
@Query(value = "UPDATE SUBSCRIPTIONFILE SET DESCRIPTION = ?1, FILENAME = ?2, VERSION = ?3 WHERE (PLATFORM = ?4 AND PRODUCTSKU = ?5)", nativeQuery = true)
    SUBSCRIPTIONFILE updateUsingEmbdedKey(String DESCRIPTION, String FILENAME, String VERSION, String PLATFORM, String PRODUCTSKU);
```

And as the debug console shows -

```
2018-12-03 18:37:02.734 DEBUG 5180 --- [           main] org.hibernate.SQL                        : UPDATE SUBSCRIPTIONFILE SET DESCRIPTION = ?, FILENAME = ?, VERSION = ? WHERE (PLATFORM = ? AND PRODUCTSKU = ?)
2018-12-03 18:37:04.405 TRACE 5180 --- [           main] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - [newDescription!]
2018-12-03 18:37:04.427 TRACE 5180 --- [           main] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [2] as [VARCHAR] - [bla bla bla]
2018-12-03 18:37:04.437 TRACE 5180 --- [           main] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [3] as [VARCHAR] - [bla]
2018-12-03 18:37:04.445 TRACE 5180 --- [           main] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [4] as [VARCHAR] - [xyz]
2018-12-03 18:37:04.455 TRACE 5180 --- [           main] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [5] as [VARCHAR] - [testSave]
```

My questions:

1 - is the query syntax is OK?

2- is there a better way to do it using a built-in `JpaRepository` query?

Entire `JpaRepository` -

```
public interface SubscriptionRepo extends JpaRepository<SUBSCRIPTIONFILE, SUBSCRIPTIONFILE_KEY>{

    @Query(value = "UPDATE SUBSCRIPTIONFILE SET DESCRIPTION = ?1, FILENAME = ?2, VERSION = ?3 WHERE (PLATFORM = ?4 AND PRODUCTSKU = ?5)", nativeQuery = true)
            SUBSCRIPTIONFILE updateUsingEmbdedKey(String DESCRIPTION, String FILENAME, String VERSION, String PLATFORM, String PRODUCTSKU);
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is an update you need a `@Modifying` annotation to go with your `@Query` annotation.